# Dynamically set time zone in active record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model - lets say `Event` which has a `starts_at` datetime column. The event model has a column time_zone (required) which saves you got it.. the time zone.

I'm dynamically setting the time zone in the controller. But what if i have a helper method in the model called lets say `started?`

```
def started?
  starts_at <= Time.zone.now
end
```

This would return the time zone configured by the application.

I could do this:

```
def started?
  Time.zone = time_zone
  starts_at <= Time.zone.now
end
```

This would do the trick - but is there any better way to do this? For the whole model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def started?
 starts_at <= Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone)
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Define it in the Model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # model stuff

  def started?
    Time.zone = self.time_zone
    self.starts_at <= Time.zone.now
  end

end
```

then you can access it as

```
@event.started?
```

Comment: It's just the same, but placed in the model instead, notice the `self`. Or already there in your code?